# Using RegEx get tags from string with any attribute instead selected on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
"<table border=\"\">border</table>
<table hrt ere we we we wr>border</table>
<table></table>
<table heaed border=\"erer\"></table>"
```

I need to get all tags without border attribute in array

Output:

```
["<table hrt ere we we we wr>border</table>",
"<table></table>"]
```

Comment: <table hrt ere we we we wr>border</table>
<table></table>

Answer (score -1):

You may try this negative lookahead based regex.

```
<table\b(?![^>]*\bborder=)[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/table>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mH6wP2/2)

```js
var s = '<table border="">border</table>\n<table hrt ere we we we wr>border</table>\n<table></table>\n<table heaed border="erer"></table>';
alert(s.match(/<table\b(?![^>]*\bborder=['"])[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/table>/g))
```